# How to get row Count of the sqlite3_stmt *statement?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Currently i am using below code to get total no. of records from statement.

```
int cnt = 0;
while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
   cnt++;
   // do something...
}
if (cnt == 0)
{
   // do something...
}
```

In Android I can easily get Count of statement using below code

```
if(cursor.getCount()>0)
{
 // do something
}
```

So, Is there any similar way to get count of statement ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979245/count-number-of-rows-in-a-sqlite-database..... Look out more in Google

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006488/get-rows-count-from-sqlite-database-in-iphone-ios this what u are looking for

Comment: @DebanjanChakraborty @the1pawan These questions are about queries that have `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Android just does the first code block internally (and caches the data).

Comment: How about Select only column and then use sqlite_count?