# how do you find the number of rows in an sqlite database using swift 4?

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am trying to find the last id in my table within the database so I can place it in another table. How can I find this id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Rows Count from sqlite database in iPhone ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006488/get-rows-count-from-sqlite-database-in-iphone-ios)

Comment: Is this an sql or Swift question? If you are already storing data in the database I guesss you have got the Swift part working?

Answer (score 3):

You don’t want the number of rows, but rather you want its last `rowid`. Generally they’re the same, but not always. What if you had deleted a row? You really want the `rowid`, which you can retrieve with [`sqlite3_last_insert_rowid`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) immediately after inserting row. That will give you the `rowid` for the previously inserted row.

---

For example, consider:

```
var db: OpaquePointer?
if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
    print("error opening database")
}

if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS author (author_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
}

var statement: OpaquePointer?

if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO author (name) VALUES (?)", -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
}

if sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, "William Shakespeare", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("failure binding: \(errmsg)")
}

if sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("failure inserting author: \(errmsg)")
}

let authorId = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db)

if sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("error finalizing prepared statement: \(errmsg)")
}
```

So, if your intent was to capture the `rowid` so that you can reference it in other tables, the `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid` will capture what SQLite generated for you. In the above example, I’m setting `authorId` constant to whatever SQLite assigned for this record.

You probably know this, but for the sake of future readers, we should generally let SQLite generate the unique `rowid` for us:

- use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (possibly [`AUTOINCREMENT`](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), as needed) in the table definition, like above; and
- don’t actually specify a value for that key when inserting, but rather let SQLite populate that.

Bottom line, we let SQLite assign `rowid` values for us and we use `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid` to capture the id of the previous row that was created.

---

For example, I can now use that `authorId` when I want to use it in another table:

```
let sql = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (
        book_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        title TEXT NOT NULL,
        author_id INTEGER,
            FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author (author_id))
    """

if sqlite3_exec(db, sql, nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
}

if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO book (title, author_id) VALUES (?, ?)", -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
}

if sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, "Henry V", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("failure binding book title: \(errmsg)")
}

if sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 2, authorId) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("failure binding author id: \(errmsg)")
}

if sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("failure inserting book: \(errmsg)")
}

if sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("error finalizing prepared statement: \(errmsg)")
}
```

Comment: Good clarification. Updated answer.

Comment: when I've put the id into the table, the identifier says its not recognised

Comment: Edit your question and provide (a) a reproducible example; (b) full text of the error; and (c) let us know if it’s a runtime error or compile-time error; and (d) at what line. But, no offense, I can’t do anything with simply “its not recognised”. But I ran the above code and it worked fine (and it’s a commonly used pattern).